# Programatically set CFBundleShortVersionString

Tags: swift, objective-c

Is it possible to programmatically update the CFBundleShortVersionString in swift for different targets without using a third party?

**Note:** I want to make the user be able to update the marketing version on run-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At build-time, `info.plist` can be modified, lots of ways, but one way is `plutil` using arguments `-replace keypath -type value` - see `man plutil`

Another way is to load the plist into a swift dictionary, mutate it, then write it back. `NSDictionary(contentsOfFile:)` would load info.plist - it's a dictionary. NSDictionary can save plist: `-writeToFile:atomically:`

Comment: You can use `avgtool` too, no? See https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1827/_index.html

Comment: Can we do it on run-time with updating the plist (your second suggestion)? [@Shadowrun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4773610/shadowrun)

Comment: No, not at run-time

Comment: I need it on run-time for our company testers. (for testing the backend services compability with old and new versions.)

Comment: If you want to have an app send versioned requests, and versioned reponses come back from a server, you can do that, but if you send CFBundleShortVersionString to the server then it's fixed. If you send some value that the user could change, maybe via some kind of debug mode UI, then that could allow testing - info.plist is immutable

Comment: thank you, using a user default value that can be managed by the user for sending to the backend can solve my problem.